# Restrict OpenVPN user to a specific port on a specific servers

Tags: networking, openvpn

The use case is kind of challenging. I need to map my openvpn Users to particular port on my machines. Say a user from developer team should only be able to access port 80 of my server whose ip is 172.31.192.8 but not port 22.

Comment: `OpenVPN` server is on your machines or not?

Answer (score 0):

Just by a firewall rule

```
iptables --append INPUT --match <YourProtocol> --protocol <YourProtocl> --src <Source network/IP> -i <input Interface> --dport 80 --jump ACCEPT
```

- `<YourProtocol>` is TCP or UDP or ICMP or whatever you need 
   (in case
  of http on port 80 TCP)
- as `<Source network/IP>` after `--src` specify the IP or network your
  Clients gets. 
   (With openVPN its usually something like 10.0.8.2 if
  you didn't change it.)
- `<Input Interface>` is the network interface on which incoming traffic reaches. 
  (For OpenVPN its usually something like tun0 )
- And finally provide the port you want to allow acces to after
  `--dport`.
   (in your case 80)
  (Hint if you want to provide acces to more than one port don't setup various rules ... use instead: `-m multiport --dports <OnePort,AnotherPort,...>`)

For more information about iptables Firewall refer to https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/iptables2/

I found this iptables generator tool quite handy for easy rules:
https://www.perturb.org/content/iptables-rules.html